# How to model user event log in cassandra?

Tags: database, cassandra, data-modeling

My given use case is fairly simple: Store events for a given user and allow to count these per user for a given timeframe later on.

The number of possible events is rather small (<1k) and so is the number of users (<10k). The number of inserts is approximately ~1k/sec. Queries are rather user-centric, so basically selecting all or specific events for a given user within a given timeframe.

The key columns are:

- username
- timestamp
- event

Currently my model looks like this column would be used as this:

```
(username, (timestamp, event, uuid))
```

Thus the username would be the partition key and most queries could be done by only querying one node. A very common query could look like that:

```
select * from user_events where username=? and timestamp>? and timestamp<?
```

I further thought about using a counter column instead of adding a separate uuid column in case the same event for the same user happens within the same millisecond.

Thus, also the table would stay smaller.

I would appreciate if somebody could share his/her thoughts on this model.

**UPDATE**

I created following main table to store the user events

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS events.events_by_user(
        user text,
        added_week int,
        added_timestamp timestamp,
        event text,
        uuid uuid,
        PRIMARY KEY((user, added_week), added_timestamp, event))
    WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY(added_timestamp DESC)
```

This worked quite nicely and I started to query the table by queries like this:

```
SELECT event,added_timestamp FROM events_by_user WHERE user=? AND added_week=? AND added_timestamp>=? AND added_timestamp<?;
```

Afterwards I created a second query to also filter out specific events:

```
SELECT event,added_timestamp FROM events_by_user WHERE user=? AND added_week=? AND added_timestamp>=? AND added_timestamp<? AND event IN ?;
```

This one though did not work, as I am not allowed to add an in-clause after doing gte and lt queries on the timestamp with following message:

> Clustering column "event" cannot be restricted (preceding column
>   "added_timestamp" is restricted by a non-EQ relation)

Comment: This may result in wide row.

Comment: I see, but how can I get pass this with the given requirements? Most queries include the username and a given time range but occasionally, also username-only queries are executed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two conflicting requirements: you want to perform `username` centric queries, but you don't want wide rows... No much operating space here...

I'd solve wide rows first. You really don't want wide rows, they'd just kill you(r nodes). So, you need to find something to couple with the `username`. From what I see, since most of your queries are based on both `username` and `timestamp`, I would select a good time granularity to control how wide the rows are.

You say

> The number of possible events is rather small (<1k) and so is the number of users (<10k). The number of inserts is approximately ~1k/sec

however you don't specify if the number of events is **per user**, and you don't specify if the insert freq is for **all users** (I'm assuming they are from now on).

Based on that, you expect 86M events per day, which translates to an average of 8600 events per user. That seems to me a decent granularity level, so I would add a timestamp in the form `yyyy-mm-dd` as partition key:

```
CREATE TABLE myevents  (
    username text,
    day timestamp,
    timestamp timestamp,
    event int
    uuid uuid,
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY ((username, day), timestamp, event, uuid)
);
```

This allows you to query flawlessy all the events belonging to a particular user in a particular day. If you need to query across multiple days then you need to perform multiple queries (one per day) and then reconstruct the results in your application by appending the results of the first day with the results of the second day, and then append the results of the third day... and so on. I say append because results are sorted by the cluster key `timestamp`.

You can select the most appropriate granularity level for your needs by changing the `day` values. If you want hour granularity change the format to `yyyy-mm-dd HH:00`, this will allow you to have smaller rows, but you'll need to perform 24 queries to fetch data for one day. Or you could chose to go with a two-days step, and now you have your rows twice as large, but you'd perform half of the queries.

Now everything depends on your needs and on your cluster. Given the high C* scalability features I'd go with more queries and smaller rows, even if that means performing some more coding at the application level. It would allow you to scale better.

Comment: I basically did as suggested, but now I have the problem that I need to query for specific events within a given timerange, this is not always the case though. When I try to query, I get an exception when I do y > ts >= x and additional event in ?. Would you suggest to add a special table for this case?

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand what you're trying to do. Can you write your query?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM events_by_user WHERE user=? AND added_week=? AND added_timestamp>=? AND added_timestamp<? AND event IN ?;`
 vs `SELECT * FROM events_by_user WHERE user=? AND added_week=? AND added_timestamp>=? AND added_timestamp<?;` Basically, the only difference is that one query also asks for specific events while the other doe snot.

Comment: @u6f6o: I see, you'll need to perform multiple `SELECT`s with `event = ?`. Even swapping `added_timestamp` and `event` is a no-no because would invalidate your first query...

Comment: I see, but that would basically mean, that I would execute the same lookup operation over and over again on the cassandra nodes with the only difference of selecting a different event every time. I also thought about selecting all rows without specifying the events and filter by hand but then I fetch too many rows :-(

Comment: Hi I have a similar problem where we have events per user, we have also the issue of having integer user_ids so we want ed to add a fixed shard_id for example userid /100000 , but we would like to avoid adding a date based query as well....  would PRIMARY KEY((shard_id, user_id, event), other_clustering_key) be ok ? we would have to keep removing older rows to keep it to a safe level I guess would work?